# Cannot connect to MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I could not connect to the local host MYSQL database using my simple php code and DOES NOT display anyything. THis is applicable to all users and root.Eventhough the problem is reported many times, i could not fix it. Also it is written in one site that it may have to make changes in php file.Please give me solution for this connection error.

I use php 5.5.9-1 in Ubuntu. MYSQL version is 5.5.38.
My code is

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);


if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

Comment: How do you run this code?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli_* or PDO instead.

Comment: Show  the output of your script

Comment: Basically i am developing a simple site and when clcik a form button, the php code is called.Output expected in browser but cannot see anything (including error)

Comment: when you run this page directly (without cliking the button of the previous page) does it run ?

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. This is where the cause of the problem is reported to.

Comment: It is showing error..PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/junglab/x.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/junglab/x.php on line 4
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /home/junglab/x.php on line 5
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/junglab/x.php on line 8

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/ani/alignment.php on line 13

Comment: Change mysql_connect() to mysqli_connect().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

This error message from your comments tells me that you do not have the MySQL extension installed.

Execute this in your terminal to install: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Then restart Apache: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Please be aware that the "mysql_" functions are marked as *deprecated* and your script might fail with a future PHP update. Please use "mysqli_" or PDO.

Comment: Yes..finally when i followed your suggestion, it connected successfully. Thanks a lot..@chrki

Answer (score 0):

`Mysql` is deprecated. Use `Mysqli`.

Create a file and name it as `db_connect.php` and copy the below code.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
```

Open browser and type `http://localhost/db_connect.php`. If you see a blank page, your connection is fine. If there's a problem, it will show you the error.

Comment: There is no connection error as i followed your suggestion@Yuva Raj

Comment: Right, then your code is fine. Include this `db_connect.php` file where you want to use database related activities.

Comment: You're welcome @anikng :)
Accept the answer, so it will help for future users who searches this topic :)